# In springboot autowired is not working, always null?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, autowired

In spring-boot application using springsecurity for writing  custom autentication.
CustomUserService is a interface and has a implementation class and a repository to fetch data from database.

```
@Component
    public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserService userService;

    @override
    someMethod(){//method of CustomUserService interface.
    userService.display();//here  "userService"  is always  null coming
    }
    }
```

kept @service on implementation & used @ComponentScan for basepackages discovery

Comment: Did you use any anotations for the CustomUserService implementation class

Comment: Put `@Service` or `@Component` on the class which implements `CustomUserService` interface and also don't forget to keep this implementing class in the radar of component scan.

Comment: show you stacktrace, the full class `CustomAuthenticationProvider` and the main class

Comment: Removed some lines :                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.example.demo.configs.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
 at

Comment: Can you show the code, where you use the CustomAuthenticationProvider class? Do you create an instance of that class by yourself with the new keyword?

Comment: I followed this code javainsimpleway.com/spring-security-using-custom-authentication-provider/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!.......some where in the code I used new Keyword to create instance of CustomAuthenticationProvider, so that's why spring is not autowiring instances inside of  CustomAuthenticationProvider class.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is only a single implementation of the interface and that implementation is annotated with @Component with Spring's component scan enabled, then Spring framework can find out the (interface, implementation) pair.

In this case, if it is null , then either the implementation class is not annotated with @Component or component scan is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you annotate `CustomUserService implementation` class `@Component` or `@Service` and  whether component scan can discover this service.

Comment: kept service annotation on implementation & ComponentScan   annotation for basepackages discovery

Comment: I have a confusion in the provided code `@override
    someMethod(){//method of CustomUserService interface.
    userService.display();//here  "userService"  is always  null coming
    }`.  for method `someMethod()` you commented as `//method of CustomUserService interface`. but you used `@override` . still the class `CustomAuthenticationProvider` implements only `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: I am using code in http://javainsimpleway.com/spring-security-using-custom-authentication-provider/  . In CustomAuthenticationProvider class, "userService" reference is always null

Comment: This also can be happen if you instantiate a object `CustomUserService` with  `new`

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot application, you don't have to explicitly enable component scan. All the annotated classes will automatically be registered as beans which are present under the package where the spring-boot application class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) is present.

So if you Application class is present in `com.abc` package all the subpackages of `com.abc` will be scanned for spring beans. Refer the tree below:

```
+--- src
|   +--- main
|   |   +--- java
|   |   |   +--- com
|   |   |   |   +--- application
|   |   |   |   |   +--- Application.java
|   |   |   |   |   +--- beans
|   |   |   |   |   |   +--- ASpringBean.java
|   |   |   |   |   |   +--- AnotherSpringBean.java
```

May be in your case the beans are not getting discovered because they are outside application class package.